# TortoiseSVN Error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have some problems with SVN. 
Can anybody help me?

When I tray to merge branch to trunk i get flowing error:

> Server sent unexpected return value
>   (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS

Same error get when tray to create new tag or branch.
I have Read/write permisions.

I use VisualSVN  and TortoiseSVN.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

403 Forbidden is one of the [HTTP Status Codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). As per the definition:

> The server understood the request, but
>   is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the
>   request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the
>   request method was not HEAD and the
>   server wishes to make public why the
>   request has not been fulfilled, it
>   SHOULD describe the reason for the
>   refusal in the entity. If the server
>   does not wish to make this information
>   available to the client, the status
>   code 404 (Not Found) can be used
>   instead.

I imagine that your repository is something like http://server/repo/project/ so try browsing that URL with your regular browser. Maybe is not related to Subversion authentication but HTTP authentication.

I know it is not a good answer, but it might give you a hint to expand the question :)